# Setting Session After Setting Headers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to implement an asynchronous method which makes a POST call to a certain API and retrieves its data, and then stores the result in the user's session. The task itself seems to be quite easy, but it gets problematic when I do it the 'fire-and-forget' style.

I do not wish to wait for the result to come back from the external API, but instead let the user load his requested page and continue browsing. Only when the response is ready, I want it saved in the session.

Everything seems to be working fine, but the only problem is the moment I set the session and proceed to the next route, everything gets lost as if I never set it in the first page. Debugging the code also shows that the process completes without any errors whatsoever, therefore I suspect an issue with setting the session after the response headers are already set. Can't seem to understand why that should be an issue, though.

I am using nodejs with express, and mongodb for session & database handling.

```
router.get('/myroute', function(req, res, next) { 
  request({
        url: endpoint,
        method: "POST",
        json: true,
        body: jsonData
    }, function(error, response, body) {
    req.session.mykey = 'some response';
  });
  res.redirect('/otherroute');
});

router.get('/checkresult', function(req, res, next) { 
  res.json(req.session.mykey);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to explicitly call `save`.

```
function(error, response, body) {
    req.session.mykey = 'some response';
    req.session.save();
}
```

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html#sessionsavecallback

> This method is automatically called at the end of the HTTP response if the session data has been altered

In your case this automatic save will be occurring too soon.

Comment: Fantastic! Works like a charm.